# Dealing with large amounts of data via XML API

Tags: php, xml, database, api, rest

So, I searched some here, but couldn't find anything good, apologies if my search-fu is insufficient...

So, what I have **today** is that my users upload a CSV text file using a form to my PHP script, and then I import that file into a database, after validating every line in it. The text file can be put to about 70,000 lines long, and each lines contains 24 fields of values. This is obviously not a problem since dealing with that kind of data. Every line needs to be validated plus I check the DB for duplicates (according to a dynamic key generated from the data) to determine if the data should be inserted or updated.

Right, but my clients are now requesting an automatic API for this, so they don't have to manually create and upload a text file. Sure, but how would I do it?

If I were to use a REST server, memory would run out pretty quickly if one request contained XML for 70k posts to be inserted, so that's pretty much out of the question.

So, how should I do it? I have thought about three options, please help med decide or add more options to the list

1. One post per request. Not all clients have 70k posts, but an update to the DB could result in the API handling 70k requests in a short period, and it would probably be daily either way.
2. X amount of posts per request. Set a limit to the number of posts that the API deals with per request is set to, say, 100 at a time. This means 700 requests.
3. The API requires for the client script to upload a CSV file ready to import using the current routine. This seems "fragile" and not very modern.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the point here. Your clients don't want to create a CSV file, but they would rather create an XML file? Maybe a little bigger spot of light into this should help us to understand better and therefore help You to decide...

Comment: They would rather use a web service, not create a XML file. Most web service methods (SOAP, REST, XMLRPC) communicate with XML, hence my reference to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this by imposing a limit of 100 posts per request, and I am using REST through PHP to handle the data. Uploading 36,000 posts takes about two minutes with all the validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you read up on SAX processing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML and HTTP Chunk Encoding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding you will see that it should be feasible to parse the XML document whilst it is being sent.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I wonder how commonplace it is. While Simple API for XML is how the data is being dealt with, you still need the sending part to handle the entire chunking of the data, would you not?  But thanks anyway for the pointer

Comment: @Sandman I would expect most Http client libraries to handle chunking for you automatically.  The ones on the Microsoft platform do.

Comment: @Sandman SAX readers are available on multiple platforms.  Not sure about php.

Answer (score -1):

First of all don't use XMl for this! Use JSON, it is fastest than xml.

I Use on my project import from xls. file is very large, but script work fine, just client must create files with same structure for import